# How to make SwiftUI view fullscreen?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

As the title already says I'm trying to make a view fullscreen (make it extend over the `SafeArea`), but `SwiftUI` seems to always align views to the `safeArea`.

After researching this for a while I found `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` which seems like a pretty straightforward way to do it. The problem is that it doesn't work. The view still isn't full screen. Here is some example code:

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Test")
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .background(Color.red)
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe all that `edgesIgnoringSafeArea` does is *center* the content of a view ignoring the safe area. The question for you is really - *why* do you wish to ignore the safe area? Apple ha been directing developers to *respect* the safe area for a few years now - and in fact I believe the will soon (if not already0 make if grounds for rejection. There is a way (at least in `UIKit`) to "ignore" the safe area... hide the status bar. Maybe find a way to do that in `SwiftUI`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Hiding the status bar actually worked, thanks, but I think I'll continue searching for a solution without having to hide the status bar.

The reason I want to ignore it is that I want to display an MKMapView at the top that's also supposed to be behind the notch (like it is in the Apple Maps app). Its just for looks tbh.

Comment: @dfd There are plenty of reasons to ignore the safe area; for example, you may want to provide a custom background for your view. It would look really ugly if you had an image for the background, but with white bars on the top and bottom. What you shouldn't put in the safe area are things like UI elements that the user directly interacts with, such as a button.

Answer (score 43):

Just swap the ..background(Color.red) and .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all). And it will work perfectly.

```swift
struct ContentView : View {

    var body: some View {
        Text("Test")
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(Color.red)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

    }
}
```

Comment: that's weird, I actually tried that already, but now it seems to work. Maybe it's just a glitch in the beta. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Is that a bug or is that how it's supposed to work?

Comment: May be it's a bug or may be not. I can't say for sure. But I realized that if I give a background color after Text("Test"), it will only color the content frame the string "Test" takes. But if I give a background color after setting a frame then it will color the whole frame.

Comment: I think it's a bug... `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` should modify the size of the View, and `.background(Color.red)` should modify the background color of the View. Instead, it seems that `.background()` is also modifying the size.

Comment: It's not a bug, it gives you flexibility over what you want to happen, though is quite confusing an awkward in a way. Basically the colour applies to the view before it's resized by any subsequent modifiers. Apply the colour first and then something like padding and the extra padding isn't coloured. Do the padding first and then colour and you get the full size view coloured.

Comment: It behaves as if there were several layers of views, creating a new view after padding. Is it the case ? Consider the following: var body: some View {
        Text("Test")
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .background(Color.red)
            .padding(25)
            .background(Color.blue)
    }.     that give a red content with a blue border and not a full blue.

Answer (score 7):

According to Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/spriteview/3606398-fullscreencover) from iOS 14 you can use fullScreenCover(item:onDismiss:content:)

And here is sample code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isFullScreen = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
        Color.yellow.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        Text("Hello, FullScreen!")
            .padding()
            .background(Color.blue)
            .foregroundColor(.green)
            .cornerRadius(8)
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isFullScreen) {
                FullScreen(isFullScreen: $isFullScreen)
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                isFullScreen.toggle()
            }
    }
    }
}

struct FullScreen: View {
    @Binding var isFullScreen: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            Text("This is full screen!!")
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.isFullScreen.toggle()
                }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well not really a solution for sheets in full-size, though a very nice solution for the underlying use case. Thanks a lot, appreciate your piece of code.

Answer (score 5):

The Augmented Reality App with SwiftUI also has a problem in entering full screen. (Xcode 12.3, SwiftUI 5.3)

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        return ARViewContainer().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

The code above is from the AR template. However, it doesn't work.

The solution is tricky: you have to set "LaunchScreen.storyboard" as "Launch Screen File" in "[yourTarget] -> General -> App Icons and Launch Images". If there is no "LaunchScreen.storyboard" in the project, it can still work by entering "LaunchScreen" in that field.

I found a [similar discussion](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/665031) on Apple forum that explains the potential reason of failure:

> If that isn't set properly, then it sounds like your app is launching into a compatibility mode which is letterboxing your app.

Comment: I had the same issue but I was using SwiftUI and SpriteKit. For whatever reason, it would not go into fullscreen. I tried this even though I don't have a launch screen file and it worked. Spent hours scratching my head over this. I'm glad it's working now though.

Answer (score 0):

```
ZStack {
                    Text("Test")
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(.clear)
                        .background(Color.clear)
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                        .contentShape(Rectangle())
                        .onTapGesture {
                            //tap action
                        }
                }
```